# How to retrieve associated objects / records that a set of users have in common through a association table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to retrieve objects / records *simultaneously* associated by two or more users. That is, I have a database table where I store association data between users and articles; I would like to "build" a *SQL query* so to retrieve associated articles by two or more users. For instance, if I have followings association objects

```
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 1, user_id: 1, article_id: 1>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 2, user_id: 1, article_id: 2>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 3, user_id: 1, article_id: 3>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 4, user_id: 2, article_id: 1>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 5, user_id: 2, article_id: 2>    
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 6, user_id: 3, article_id: 1>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 7, user_id: 3, article_id: 3>
#<UserArticleAssociation id: 8, user_id: 4, article_id: 4>
```

I would to state / run a *scope method* so to get something like the following:

```
@user1.articles.associated_by(@user2)
# => [ #<UserArticleAssociation id: 1, user_id: 1, article_id: 1>,
       #<UserArticleAssociation id: 4, user_id: 2, article_id: 1>]

@user1.articles.associated_by(@user3)
# => [ #<UserArticleAssociation id: 1, user_id: 1, article_id: 1>,
       #<UserArticleAssociation id: 7, user_id: 3, article_id: 3>]

@user1.articles.associated_by(@user4)
# => nil

@user2.articles.associated_by(@user3)
# => [ #<UserArticleAssociation id: 1, user_id: 1, article_id: 1>]

@user1.articles.associated_by([@user2, @user3])
# => [ #<UserArticleAssociation id: 1, user_id: 1, article_id: 1>]
```

In others words, *I would like to find articles that a set of users have in common through the `user_article_associations` table*. How can I make that?

---

Involved classes are stated as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_associations, :class_name  => 'UserArticleAssociation'
  has_many :articles, :through => :article_associations
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_associations
  has_many :users, :through => :user_associations
end
```

Comment: Could you explain the relationship between `@user1` and `@user2` that would return the results in your first example?

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott - I updated the question.

Comment: Does "associated by" really make sense here? Isn't what you're trying to do just get all ArticleAssociations belonging to any of a set of users? What does UserArticleAssociation look like?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - I am trying to get all articles **simultaneously** associated by one or more users.

Comment: @user502052 What does "simultaneously" mean? You want associations where one article is associated with the given users? Your second example doesn't do that, though. Your fourth and fifth can't, either, since they return only a single association, which isn't possible given each user has one association and more than one user must be given.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - **(1)** *What does "simultaneously" mean?* It means that I am looking for articles associated in the first example by both `@user1` and `@user2`, in the second example by both `@user1` and `@user3`, and so on; **(2)** My second example seems to be correct as that said in **(1)**; **(3)** It is not true: it is possible since **(1)**.

Comment: Is this restatement valid? You want to find articles that a set of users have in common through the user_article_associations table.

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott - Yes, your "re-statement" is valid and "simplifies" what I am trying to explain (I updated the question by adding your "re-statement").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use having clause with group_by

```
Article.joins(:user_article_associations).
where('user_article_associations.user_id in (?)', users_ids)).
group('articles.id').
having('COUNT(user_article_associations.user_id in (?)) = ?',users_ids, users_ids.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to combine the relations:

```
articles = @user1.articles.merge(@user2.articles)
```

This will get you all Articles that `@user1` & `@user2` share. You can further call `merge` with additional relations for Articles, e.g.:

```
articles = @user1.articles.merge(@user2.articles).merge(@user3.articles)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make that in a single SQL query?

Comment: @user502052 I don't think so. If so it'd be rather complicated and likely not doable in pure ActiveRecord.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to make that with some wise usage of SQL `AND` / `OR` clauses (or some other SQL clause that I do not know), but I can not find out how!

Comment: @user502052 You can probably do it with a grouped self-join and virtual columns, but you'd need N self-joins for N users you're querying against.

Comment: Can you "inspire" me on how I could join the `user_article_associations` table to itself in my case?

Comment: @user502052 Look up how to do self-joins. You'd basically do it so that you can join on the article id and get two user columns and find where you have them both. But I'd really recommend seeing if the N queries is really that much overhead in your app before coming up with a complex pure SQL query.

Comment: Thank you for your "inspiration". I tryed to implement something in order to "join on the article id and get two user columns and find where you have them both", but I am in trouble on making that. More, I thought **(1)** to join the *`user_article_associations`* table so to retrieve in that table all objects "created by" / "associated by" given users; **(2)** to "filter" (through SQL clauses on article ids) associated objects "in common to" all given users. ... the latter is the hard part for which I find myself in trouble again.

Comment: I opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496959/how-to-retrieve-common-records-in-the-same-database-table-through-a-single-sql) after your "inspiration".

Comment: *For now*, I think it is better to leave the rating to `0` and *then* (that is, only *after* the linked question - the ["new question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496959/how-to-retrieve-common-records-in-the-same-database-table-through-a-single-sql) in the previous comment - has been answered) to vote up (if that linked question has success) / down (otherwise) your answer. I also think your "then" means that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
Article.joins(:users).where('users.id in (?)', my_users.map(&:id)).group('articles.id')
```