# How to retrieve "common" records in the same database table through a single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails (version 3.2.2) and mysql2 (version 0.3.11 - MySQL version 5.2.38). While discussing on "[How to retrieve associated objects / records that a set of users have in "common" through a association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494046/how-to-retrieve-associated-objects-records-that-a-set-of-users-have-in-common)"*  I found myself in a "specific" situation in which I have to find "associated objects / records"** by running a *single* - for performance reasons - SQL query on a association database table. Particularly, *I would like to make that in order to retrieve **only** previously mentioned "associated objects / records" where `user_id`* (representing a `foreign key` "pointing" to a `User` object) *and `article_id`* (representing a `foreign key` "pointing" to a `Article` object) *column values are the same* (that is, where `article_id` and `user_id` are "common").

How could / should I retrieve "associated objects / records" (maybe, by using some facility in a Ruby on Rails and / or SQL / database "way" / "context") in my case?

---

* Specifically, after *@Andrew Marshall* posted his / her answer.

** *Note*: those "associated objects / records" are related to a `has_many :through` Ruby on Rails [`ActiveRecord::Associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations.html) described in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494046/how-to-retrieve-associated-objects-records-that-a-set-of-users-have-in-common).

Comment: what do you mean, related objects, e.g. all the clients who've purchasecd product X?

Comment: @Marc B - I updated the question, detailing it.

Comment: can u provide the model associations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a raw-sql way to pull out what you want, I think:

```
select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = 1) and user_id = 2;
```

Where you can substitute user ids in Rails:

```
ArticlesUser.find_by_sql(["select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = ?) and user_id = ?", @user1.id, @user2.id])
```

Or for multiple ids::

```
ArticlesUser.find_by_sql(["select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = ?) and user_id IN (?)", @user1.id, [@user2.id,@user3.id]])
```

So from sample data (from your other questions):

```
mysql> select * from articles_users;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | article_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 |
|  2 |       1 |          2 |
|  3 |       1 |          3 |
|  4 |       2 |          1 |
|  5 |       2 |          2 |
|  6 |       3 |          1 |
|  7 |       3 |          3 |
|  8 |       4 |          4 |
+----+---------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will return values thus:

```
mysql> select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = 1) and user_id = 2;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | article_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  4 |       2 |          1 |
|  5 |       2 |          2 |
+----+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = 1) and user_id = 3;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | article_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  6 |       3 |          1 |
|  7 |       3 |          3 |
+----+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or for multiple user-ids:

```
mysql> select * from articles_users where article_id in (select articles.id from articles inner join articles_users on articles_users.article_id = articles.id where user_id = 1) and user_id in (2,3);
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | article_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  4 |       2 |          1 |
|  5 |       2 |          2 |
|  6 |       3 |          1 |
|  7 |       3 |          3 |
+----+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You've asked for a sql way - but there's almost certainly a railsy way to do this... but this should get you started, and you can refactor it down from here.